# How to cache pip packages within Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, caching, pip, azure-pipelines

Although [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) provides a lot of information on caching within Azure pipelines, it is not clear how to cache Python pip packages for a Python project.

How to proceed if one is willing to cache Pip packages on an Azure pipelines build?

According to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/adding-caching-to-azure-pipelines/), it may be so that pip cache will be enabled by default in the future. As far as I know it is not yet the case.

Comment: What kind of pip packages on Azure pipelines you want to use ?  Are you trying to use private packages. It's able to directly host private pip packages using Azure Artifacts

Comment: I would like to have a similar behavior to https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#pip-cache.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, I have the impression pip packages are already being cached by default. Can you confirm that? For example pip packages are being installed to /home/vsts/.cache/pip folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the `pre-commit` documentation as inspiration:

- https://pre-commit.com/#azure-pipelines-example
- https://github.com/asottile/azure-pipeline-templates/blob/master/job--pre-commit.yml

and configured the following Python pipeline with Anaconda:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  CONDA_ENV: foobar-env
  CONDA_HOME: /usr/share/miniconda/envs/$(CONDA_ENV)/

steps:
- script: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
  displayName: Add conda to PATH

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Use cached Anaconda environment
  inputs:
    key: conda | environment.yml
    path: $(CONDA_HOME)
    cacheHitVar: CONDA_CACHE_RESTORED

- script: conda env create --file environment.yml
  displayName: Create Anaconda environment (if not restored from cache)
  condition: eq(variables.CONDA_CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')

- script: |
    source activate $(CONDA_ENV)
    pytest
  displayName: Run unit tests
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @marek-grzenkowicz. Can you also provide a non Conda solution? Maybe using pip-tools pip-sync command is a way to emulate conda environment synchronization.

Comment: I simplified the pipeline by using `cacheHitVar`. Now you can simply replace `conda env create ...` with any other command to install the dependencies (e.g. `pip install -r requirements.txt`), change the path to be cached and it will work.

Comment: We need now to understand if pip packages are already being cached by default within Azure pipelines.

Comment: Even if package files are cached within Azure infrastructure, installing them may take a significant portion of time. In my case, caching a complete Anaconda environment shortened the pipeline execution time from ~5 minutes to ~1:30.

Answer (score 7):

To cache a standard pip install use this:

```
variables:
  # variables are automatically exported as environment variables
  # so this will override pip's default cache dir
  - name: pip_cache_dir
    value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pip

steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'pip | "$(Agent.OS)" | requirements.txt'
      restoreKeys: |
        pip | "$(Agent.OS)"
      path: $(pip_cache_dir)
    displayName: Cache pip

  - script: |
      pip install -r requirements.txt
     displayName: "pip install"
```

Comment: I wonder why $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pip should be correct. I would have assumed that the directory 
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (or a shell variable or command to find that path?) has to be specifed?

Comment: You are overriding the directory so you can provide the one you are going to populate the cache with.  It could be anywhere but you’re going to want it under your workspace

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't very happy with the standard pip cache implementation that is mentioned in the official documentation. You basically always install your dependencies normally, which means that pip will perform loads of checks that take up time. Pip will find the cached builds (*.whl, *.tar.gz) eventually, but it all takes up time. You can opt to use `venv` or `conda` instead, but for me it lead to buggy situations with unexpected behaviour. What I ended up doing instead was using `pip download` and `pip install` separately:

```
variables:
  pipDownloadDir: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pip

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Load cache
  inputs:
    key: 'pip | "$(Agent.OS)" | requirements.txt'
    path: $(pipDownloadDir)
    cacheHitVar: cacheRestored

- script: pip download -r requirements.txt --dest=$(pipDownloadDir)
  displayName: "Download requirements"
  condition: eq(variables.cacheRestored, 'false')

- script: pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links=$(pipDownloadDir)
  displayName: "Install requirements"
```

Comment: That’s an interesting solution, didn’t know that existed.  You may want to make your key be just your requirements file.  From my understanding it can fall back to less precise caches like other pipeline runs, so your pip install might fail if you don’t have the exact versions you need

Comment: Never mind what I said about the requirements file.  That is how restoreKeys works.